# Swift: ScrollView Scrolling as per Cell Image Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `viewController` which has `CollectionView` and the collectionView cell contain the `ImageView` and response is from the `api`. And the `viewController orientation` is `Landscape`. So issue is when i scroll the image it's not scrolling properly. Here is the attach image.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

So how can I set the `Scrolling action` as per the my image Size. So it's display only image in View. Here is my code.

```
extension GalleryViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
            let image = arrImgs[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblIndex.text = "< \(indexPath.row+1) / \(arrImgs.count) >  Images"
            if let imgUrl = URL.init(string: image.Message) {
                cell.imgV.sd_setImage(with: imgUrl) { (img, error, casheType, url) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.imgV.image = img
                    }
                }
            }
            return cell
        }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrImgs.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize.init(width: width, height: height)
    }
}

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblIndex: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imgV: UIImageView!

}
```

This is my `StoryBord` Arrangement.

[image: image 3]

Thanks.

Comment: Set collection view's `Paging Enable` property to `true` will help you.

Comment: can you explain briefly with code.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia What do you meant by **as per the my image Size** ?? What is the issue with scrolling? Please explain.

Comment: @dahiya_boy as you can see that the two image is showing at a time.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia Yeah, whats your requirement ?? Update your question by clearly mentioning the all requrements and what actually you getting right now.

Comment: So i want only one image at time when i scroll

Comment: Set cell width as per screen width and centre align image view will fix your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser?ref=ioscookies.com